# SWIG (Java): How do I pass a struct with callback functions to C++ from an Android application?

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, swig

I am developing a real-time communication app (video and audio) for Android using a WebRTC-based C++ code library. I generate a JNI bridge using SWIG to access the native code from Java. The behaviour of the call is determined via a number of callback functions that are defined in the application layer and passed in a struct to the library code. The function for passing these callbacks looks like this:

`void registerCallbacks(CALL_CALLBACKS* callbacks);`

where `CALL_CALLBACKS` is a struct containing a number of callback functions as exemplified here:

```
struct CALL_CALLBACKS {
    // CALL_STATE is an Enum
    // Called whenever the state of the call changes
    void (*statusCallback)(CALL_STATE);

    // FRAME is a struct representing a video frame
    // Called whenever the other participant sends a video frame, typically at 30 fps
    void (*frameCallback)(const FRAME*);

    // ...
}
```

The issue is that when I let SWIG do its thing by default, the result is unusable. It generates a java type `CALL_CALLBACKS` which contains setters and getters for each of the callbacks, which are also types generated by SWIG. However, these types are named along the lines of `SWIGTYPE_p_f_ENUM_CALL_STATUS__void` and are nothing but wrappers for C pointers.

How can I write my SWIG interface file in order to pass callbacks (preferably with less nonsensical names) to the C++ library? I assume typemaps can be used somehow but I just can't wrap my head around how that can be done.

Comment: Will you have multiple concurrent callback objects? There is no userdata pointer, so you have to smuggle the Java receiver object to the C++ code somehow.

Comment: @Botje there will not be any concurrent callback objects. Could you elaborate what you mean by "smuggling the receiver object"?

Comment: In my answer, the receiver is smuggled to the callback functions as a simple global variable. You could devise more elaborate schemes using thread locals or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think SWIG can do this by itself. Here's how I would do it in plain JNI:

First, create a Java interface that you can implement on the Java side.

```java
interface Callbacks {
  void statusCallback(int status);
  void frameCallback(Frame frame);
  static native void registerCallbacks(Callbacks cb);
}
```

Next, create functions that forward the C++ arguments to a `jobject g_receiver` that implements the interface:

```cpp
jobject g_receiver;
void my_statusCallback(CALL_STATE s) {
   if (!g_receiver) {
      // Print a warning?
      return;
   }

   JNIEnv *env = getEnv();
   env->PushLocalFrame(10);

   jclass cls_Callbacks = env->GetObjectClass(g_receiver);
   jmethodID mid_Callbacks_statusCallback = env->GetMethodID(cls_Callbacks, "statusCallback", "(I)V");
   env->CallVoidMethod(g_receiver, mid_Callbacks_statusCallback, s);
   env->PopLocalFrame(nullptr);
}

void my_frameCallback(const FRAME* frame) {
   if (!g_receiver) {
      // Print a warning?
      return;
   }

   JNIEnv *env = getEnv();
   env->PushLocalFrame(10);

   // Create a Frame object from the C++ pointer.
   // See Proxy classes at http://swig.org/Doc4.0/Java.html#Java_imclass
   jclass cls_Frame = env->FindClass("Frame");
   jmethodID ctr_Frame = env->GetMethodID(cls_Frame, "<init>", "(JZ)V");
   jobject jFrame = env->NewObject(cls_Frame, ctr_Frame, (jlong) frame, (jboolean)false);
   jmethodID mid_Frame_delete = env->GetMethodID(cls_Frame, "delete", "(LFrame;)V");

   jclass cls_Callbacks = env->GetObjectClass(g_receiver);
   jmethodID mid_Callbacks_frameCallback = env->GetMethodID(cls_Callbacks, "frameCallback", "(LFrame;)V");
   env->CallVoidMethod(g_receiver, mid_Callbacks_frameCallback, jFrame);

   env->CallVoidMethod(jFrame, mid_Frame_delete); // Disconnect the Java Frame object from the C++ FRAME object.
   env->PopLocalFrame(nullptr);
}

CALL_CALLBACKS global_callbacks = { my_statusCallback, my_frameCallback };
```

Finally, you can implement `Callbacks#registerCallbacks` as follows. This is a bit more tricky because you have to make sure g_receiver is either nullptr or a valid global reference:

```cpp
JNIEXPORT void Java_Callbacks_registerCallbacks(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls_Callbacks, jobject receiver) {
    if (g_receiver) {
       env->DeleteGlobalRef(g_receiver);
    }

    g_receiver = receiver ? env->NewGlobalRef(receiver) : nullptr;
    registerCallbacks(global_callbacks);
}
```

I made some assumptions:

- You did not use any package when generating the code. That will affect the JNI method names and any references to classes in signatures.
- I am assuming your native code runs on a different thread, so the `getEnv` function should use the JNI invocation API to attach the current thread [as a daemon thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#attach_current_thread_as_daemon). You can stash the pointer in another global variable.
- Since you're on Android, you can only call `FindClass` from the main thread. You can work around this by creating a global reference to the class in the `JNI_Onload` method or hack around it by adding a `Class<Frame> getFrameClass()` method to the `Callbacks` interface. Or you can take the *very* long way round by doing the equivalent of `g_receiver.getClass().getClassLoader().findClass("Frame")`.
- You did not specify whether the `frameCallback` needs to free the FRAME object itself. My code assumes it does not and disconnects the Java object so you cannot accidentally use it after the callback ends.
- You did not specify whether the native `registerCallbacks` could be called multiple times, so I assumed it does. You could also call `registerCallbacks` as part of `JNI_Onload`.